# Is there a way to combine grid column definitions in Xamarin C#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's what I have:

```
var grid = new Grid();
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1) });
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
```

Is there a way I can combine any of these lines together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of at present but if it is something you are doing often then you could make it easier via an extension method...

```
public static class GridExtensions
{
    public static Grid Add(this Grid grid, ColumnDefinition columnDefinition)
    {
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition);
        return grid;
    }

    public static Grid AddColumnDefinition(this Grid grid, GridLength gridLength) =>
        grid.Add(new ColumnDefinition {Width = gridLength});
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
grid.AddColumnDefinition(new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star))
    .AddColumnDefinition(new GridLength(1))
    .AddColumnDefinition(new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star));
```

You could even take it a step further and accept the parameters for constructing `GridLength` and do that inside your extension method.

I am happy to accept that this is not providing fewer lines but it is less verbose and easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Create an [extension method](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-extension-method)

**Usage**

```
//<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
//     <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
//     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
//     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
//     <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
//</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
// above Xaml equivalent
grid.AddColumnDefinitions("2*", "*", "Auto", "50");
grid.AddColumnDefinitions(); //equivalent to adding a column with 1*
```

**Code**

*write sanity checks for syntax etc. to ensure code doesn't break.*

```
public static class GridExtensions
{
   public static Grid AddColumnDefinitions(this Grid grid, params string[] columndefinitions)
   {
       if (columndefinitions == null || columndefinitions.Length < 1)
       {
           grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Star });
           return grid;
       }

       foreach (var columnDef in columndefinitions)
       {
           if (columnDef.Equals("Auto"))
               grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
           else if (columnDef.Contains("*"))
           {
               string columnWidth = columnDef.Replace("*", string.Empty);
               if (columnWidth.Equals(string.Empty))
                   grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Star });
               else if (int.TryParse(columnWidth, out int colWidth))
                   grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(colWidth, GridUnitType.Star) });
           }
           else if (int.TryParse(columnDef, out int colDef))
               grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(colDef, GridUnitType.Absolute) });
        }

        return grid;
   }
}
```

P.S. Credit: A little spin on the answer by **Bijington**.

Answer (score 0):

You could write

```
var grid = new Grid(){ ColumnDefinitions = {
        new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
        new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1) },
        new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) }}};
```